# How do I correctly set ownership of a cifs mount?

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I have attempted to mount a windows share using the following line in my fstab:

```
//some_mount /media/some_mount cifs uid=1000,gid=1000,credentials=/home/quant/.smbcredentials,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

When I run `sudo mount -a` the `/media/some_mount` directory is correctly mounted. I can also see that the permissions for the directories are correct (ie. my user has read/write permission). However, when I try to enter one of the directories I get the following error:

```
-bash: cd: some_mount/dir/: Operation not permitted
```

If I first run `sudo -i` and run that same command as root, everything works.

I have tried running `id -g quant` and `id -u quant` and confirmed that my `gid` and `uid` are both 1000.

Why can't I access those directories as the non-root user?

Comment: You say your user has read/write permission. However, to enter a directory you need *execute* permission. Do you have that?

Answer (score 2):

As @terdon points out you need execute permissions to traverse a directory. Check the permissions on the mount point `/media/some_mount` in your example. 
I'll use `/mnt` for my example

```
$ ll /mnt
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Oct 24 01:42 ./
```

You'll note that while only the owner (root in my example) has write permissions and both the group (root in my example) and everyone else has read and execute permissions meaning anyone can see the contents of and traverse the directory. `chmod` is the key to setting permissions. After determining how the permissions are currently set, adjust them according to your requirements. For details on how to do this see the `man chmod` page. If you need further guidance, drop me a comment and I'll do what I can to help.